# Indentation of conditional comments in web-mode.el

Tags: web-mode

I want to set the indentation of conditional comments to 2 space, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://...)
```

The default is 4, like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://...)
```

NOTE:

I have tried without web-mode, just builtin HtmlMode and SgmlMode, and the behavior is the same: I can't modify conditional comments indentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to do so.
Please open an issue on github and describe very precisely the behavior you expect. Do not forget in your issue to link to a complete example on gist.

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of how to customize indentation settings for `web-mode` in your init file from the [web-mode documentation](http://web-mode.org/):

> HTML element offset indentation

```
(setq web-mode-markup-indent-offset 2)
```

> CSS offset indentation

```
(setq web-mode-css-indent-offset 2)
```

> Script/code offset indentation (for JavaScript, Java, PHP, Ruby, VBScript, Python, etc.)

```
(setq web-mode-code-indent-offset 2)
```

> By default, tag attributes are indented like this:

```
<img src="pix.png"
     class="noborder"/>
```

> You can force a fixed indentation with `web-mode-attr-indent-offset`

```
<img src="pix.png"
  class="noborder"/>
```

I think one of these should work for you. If none of these works for you, it might be related to [this issue](https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode/issues/554).

Comment: I have tried all that before. None works for me. Specially I tried the last one, but seem not to apply to conditional comments. I've tried set variable `standard-indent` to 2, as is mentioned in the web-mode docs but doesn't work.

Comment: @Ignativs See the issue on github that I linked to in my answer. Even though it is talking about javascript block comments, I think it is still relevant.